# My App's "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have a simple app for searching a db of Albums by artist.
Three components: App, AlbumList, AlbumSearch.

The App component defines `getAlbumsByArtist` to fetch and update albums,
and passes albums as prop to AlbumList.

App defines `getAlbumsByArtist` to pass as prop to AlbumSearch.
In AlbumSearch, when the artist is changed, I useEffect to call `getAlbumsByArtist`.

The app works, but in AlbumSearch I get a warning of
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getAlbumsByArtist'.

How can I refactor to fix this warning?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAlbums();
  }, []);

  function getAlbums() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setAlbums(data));
  }

  function getAlbumsByArtist(artist) {
    fetch(`"http://localhost:3001"/albums?artist=${artist}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setAlbums(data));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Albums</h2>
      <AlbumSearch getAlbumsByArtist={getAlbumsByArtist} />
      <AlbumList albums={albums} />
    </div>
  );
}

function AlbumSearch({ getAlbumsByArtist }) {
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getAlbumsByArtist(artist);
  }, [artist]);

  const handleArtist = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setArtist(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={`album-search ${showSearchClass}`}>
      <div>
        <label>Artist contains: </label>
        <input
          id="searchArtist"
          type="text"
          value={artist}
          onChange={handleArtist}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function AlbumList({ albums }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <div>Id</div> <div>Artist</div> <div>Title</div>{" "}
      </header>
      <div>
        {albums &&
          albums.map((album) => {
            return (
              <div key={album.id}>
                <div>{album.id}</div>
                <div>{album.artist}</div>
                <div>{album.title}</div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add getAlbumsByArtist as a dependency?

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks. But it seems odd that getAlbumsByArtist would be a dependency, since it doesn't change. I thought the point of useEffect is to monitor things that change.

Comment: It's coming in as a prop. _You_ might know that it won't change, but React doesn't know that. It's possible for your component to be used with different/changing getAlbumsByArtist functions.

Comment: but the getAlbumsByArtist is function not a state why it's required in dependencies array?

Comment: OP and @BoussadjraBrahim `getAlbumsByArtist` is redeclared every time `App` rerenders, i.e. when `albums` is updated. OP *could* use `useCallback` to memoize the passed callback, though that wouldn't resolve the esLint issue flagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As react will guarantee that a `setState()` function will never change, you can simply add the `getAlbumsByArtist` function to your `useEffect()` dependencies to get the same result.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getAlbumsByArtist(artist);
  }, [getAlbumsByArtist, artist]);
```

Another way would be to simply irgnore the warning by:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   getAlbumsByArtist(artist);
}, [getAlbumsByArtist, artist]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```